# Countup timer on quiz

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a quiz that I have to show a countup timer while one user is taken the quiz, but I don't know how to do it because I saw jquery_countdown module but it only works for count down.
Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did this solution:

```
Tiempo transcurrido: <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var totalSeconds = localStorage.getItem("totalSeconds") || 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime()
    {
        ++totalSeconds;
        localStorage.setItem("totalSeconds", totalSeconds);
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    }

    function pad(val)
    {
        var valString = val + "";
        if(valString.length < 2)
        {
            return "0" + valString;
        }
        else
        {
            return valString;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I use localstorage because I need that counter keep his state. I reset this counter when I entry on the start page quiz.